# .NET date parsing when no year specified

Tags: datetime, cultureinfo, tryparse

I have a situation where only on 1 particular server the `DateTime.tryParse()` method is behaving incorrectly.

The server was installed with an en-US culture, but has since been changed to en-AU.  Even without that, we are using an 'en-AU' culture info with the call to `TryParse.`

The string '1/6' is parsed correctly to mean 1 June 2013 on every server we have apart from this one.  All of the other servers were probably installed as 'en-AU' but I would hope that should not change anything.  This one server parses in to mean January 6 2013.

When we create the the `CultureInfo` we use the constructor which forces the `useUserDefault` to false which would seem to force a standard en-AU culture.
Has anyone played with this form of parsing - where no year is specified and a non US culture was in play on the server at some point?

The code in question:

```
    UserCulture = new CultureInfo('en-AU', false)

    public DateTime? ParseDateTimeString(string s, bool useTime)
    {
        DateTime? result = null;
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(s, UserCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
        {
            if (s.Length == 3 && s.Substring(1, 1) == "/")
            {
                Logger.logDebugForce("Parsed datetime string [" + s + "] with culture:"+UserCulture.DisplayName +" datetimeformat.shortdatepattern:"+UserCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern+"; got:"+dt.ToString("s"));
            }
            if (useTime && DateTimeEx.HasTimeComponent(dt))
            {
                dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dt, UserTimeZone);
            }
            result = dt;
        }
        return result;
    }

    ParseDateTimeString("1/6",false); //returns June 6 2013 on all servers except one, which returns january 6 2013.
```

Cheers

Comment: The only question was your last sentence, which of course the answer is simply "yes".  Please edit your question to more specifically ask something.  The behavior you describe makes sense.

Comment: Also, `useUserDefault` must be your own variable, as it's not part of the framework.  Please show repeatable code sample that demonstrates the problem.  Thanks.